# Java RMI: Remote Interface not found, throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, only works after Fresh Boot

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

During a Java RMI program, the Remote Interface(CalcInterface.java) seems to be missing.
All the java files are in the project's src folder(I'm using IDEA). No gradle, maven nothing.
There are:

- CalcClass.java
- CalcInterface.java
- Client.java
- Server.java

They're all compiled the project's `out/production/RMI` directory.
RMI is the name of the project.

IDEA gives no compilation error.
But, on running Server.main()
I get the following exception:

```
Server Exception:java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalcInterface
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalcInterface
...
```

It works when it's a fresh boot, but after I ctrl+C the Server program and re-run it. It never works again. And Yes, I am freeing up the ports and also restarting rmiregistry.
I don't understand why it can't access CalcInterface.

I have also tried compiling all those java files by using javac in the src folder and then running `java Server` but that gives the same error.

Dumping the four java files here cuz I don't know how else to specify the problem.
`CalcInterface.java`

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface CalcInterface extends Remote {
    int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
    int subtract(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
    int multiply(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
    double divide(int a,int b) throws RemoteException, ArithmeticException;
}
```

`CalcClass.java`

```java
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class CalcClass implements CalcInterface{

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a+b;
    }

    @Override
    public int subtract(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a-b;
    }

    @Override
    public int multiply(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a*b;
    }

    @Override
    public double divide(int a, int b) throws RemoteException, ArithmeticException {
        return (double)a/b;
    }
}
```

`Server.java`

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
//            Instantiating implementation class
            CalcClass obj = new CalcClass();

//            Exporting object of implementation class to stub
            CalcInterface stub = (CalcInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj,5000);

//            Binding stub to registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

            registry.bind("Calculator", stub);
            System.out.println("Server Ready");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Server Exception:" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Not enclosing `Client.java` as I don't think it has anything to do with the issue.
Any advice of on the problem or generally regarding RMI or Java is greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. Turns out, I have to start ```rmiregistry  &``` in the same folder as that of my .class files. 
I was starting it elsewhere, hence it was unable to find the other classes.   

I am unable to mark this question as solved, it'd be appreciated if a mod or admin could do it and mark this comment as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `java.rmi.server.codebase` property.
This act as a  source, from which to load classes into a virtual machine.

You can refer it from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html).

Comment: This is not sufficient. You also need to run an HTTP server to serve the classes.